# Ioremapped address in kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I have basic query about ioremap used to map device IO addressed into kernel's virtual memory.

I would like to know if returned address from ioremap is passed to routines like virt_to_phys(), would it return back Device IO address ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`virt_to_phys()` is only valid for virtual addresses within the kernel linear map, since it's just some fast address arithmetic, not a full software table walk. The linear map normally only covers RAM. The virtual address returned by `ioremap()`, however, will usually (probably always, but I don't have the patience to check every implementation) be a vmalloc address, so if you pass that to `virt_to_phys()` you'll get nonsense back.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see your point about fast address arithmetic, it simply subtract some offset address from virtual address to get physical address . But is there any api that can be used to return back Device IO address  from virtual address returned by ioremap ?

Comment: The usual method is probably "remember what you called `ioremap()` on in the first place". I'm struggling to think of a valid reason for wanting the physical address of some mapped device _outside_ that device's driver, and within the driver you can just stash the physical address in your private data alongside the CPU address if you know you're going to want it in future (e.g. for setting up a dmaengine request).