# Access physical address from kernel space in Linux

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, kernel-module, memory-mapping

I'm writing a kernel module that needs access to a memory region outside the Kernel and User spaces. I know the physical address and the size of such a memory. I've tried with ioremap(), but the virtual address returned by such a function points to a phisical address different from the one I gave as an argument to ioremap. Then I tried to use phys_to_virt() after ioremap(), this time the virtual address obtained points to the correct physical one, however when I try to access an element inside such memory area I get the following error: *Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffff801400000f*
What I'm wrong?

EDIT:
Code snippet:

```
#define FLAG_SIZE 1
#define BUF_SIZE 4
#define ELEM_SIZE 5

res = ioremap_nocache(MEMORY_ADDR, BUF_SIZE*ELEM_SIZE);
void *virt = phys_to_virt(MEMORY_ADDR);

        
printk(KERN_INFO "Physical address %px mapped in virtual address %px\n", virt_to_phys(virt), virt);
    
// DEBUG: print buffers content
char *flags = res + BUF_SIZE*(ELEM_SIZE-FLAG_SIZE);
for(i=0; i < BUF_SIZE; i++){
        printk(KERN_INFO "row %d [flag: %c]: %d\n", i, readb(flags + i), virt + i*ELEM_SIZE);
}
```

where:
-MEMORY_ADDR: is the physical address
-BUF_SIZE: number of elements in the buffer
-ELEM_SIZE: size of the elements

The flags buffers is an array of chars at the end of such memory region

The full outputs returned are:

```
Physical address 1409286144 mapped in virtual address 335544320
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffff801400000f
Mem abort info:
  ESR = 0x96000006
  EC = 0x25: DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
  SET = 0, FnV = 0
  EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
Data abort info:
  ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000006
  CM = 0, WnR = 0
swapper pgtable: 4k pages, 39-bit VAs, pgdp=00000000407c8000
[ffffff801400000f] pgd=000000004fffb003, pud=000000004fffb003, pmd=0000000000000000
Internal error: Oops: 96000006 [#1] SMP
Modules linked in: source(O)
CPU: 1 PID: 107 Comm: ifconfig Tainted: G           O      5.4.88 #1
Hardware name: linux,dummy-virt (DT)
pstate: 20000005 (nzCv daif -PAN -UAO)
pc : getFlag+0x24/0x40 [source]
lr : shmem_net_open+0x168/0x2c0 [source]
sp : ffffffc010b4b9d0
x29: ffffffc010b4b9d0 x28: 0000000000001043 
x27: ffffff800e2b4c00 x26: ffffffc01077c000 
x25: 0000000000000005 x24: ffffffc008661158 
x23: 0000000000000004 x22: 0000000000000000 
x21: ffffff800e24e200 x20: ffffff800e255000 
x19: ffffff800e255858 x18: 0000000000020000 
x17: 000000004a0b804e x16: 0000000031b76cb0 
x15: ffffffc010859c40 x14: 0720072007200720 
x13: 0720073007320733 x12: 0734073407350735 
x11: 0733073307200773 x10: 0773076507720764 
x9 : 076407610720076c x8 : 000000000000006f 
x7 : 076907760720076e x6 : 0000000000000001 
x5 : ffffff800e255840 x4 : 0000000000000005 
x3 : 0000008040000000 x2 : 0000000000000000 
x1 : 000000000000000f x0 : ffffff801400000f 
Call trace:
 getFlag+0x24/0x40 [source]
 __dev_open+0xe4/0x160
 __dev_change_flags+0x160/0x1c0
 dev_change_flags+0x20/0x60
 devinet_ioctl+0x63c/0x700
 inet_ioctl+0x2f4/0x360
 sock_do_ioctl+0x44/0x2b0
 sock_ioctl+0x1c8/0x510
 do_vfs_ioctl+0x984/0xb70
 ksys_ioctl+0x44/0x90
 __arm64_sys_ioctl+0x1c/0xc0
 el0_svc_common.constprop.0+0x68/0x160
 el0_svc_handler+0x6c/0x90
 el0_svc+0x8/0x1fc
Code: 1b047c21 8b21c041 8b010000 cb030000 (39400000) 
---[ end trace 5a219c0b95978c47 ]---
Segmentation fault
```

The processor used is an Armv8 cortex 53

EDIT 2: corrected the previous code snippets, now no kernel panic, however the output is incorrect:

```
[SHMEM_NET] Physical address 0000000054000000 mapped in virtual address ffffffc01000d000
row 0 [flag: ]: 268488704
row 1 [flag: E]: 268488707
row 2 [flag: E]: 268488710
row 3 [flag: E]: 268488713
row 4 [flag: E]: 268488716
```

The issue is that I should find the first 'E' at row 0 and row 4 should be instead outside the mapped region. Moreover if now I modify such memory region, the modifications can be seen by this machine, but other machines accessing same memory regions still sees the old values.

Comment: Can you share code snipped, processor type and relevant kernel log?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761757/5264491

Comment: Thanks @IanAbbott however, still a question remains? Why the content of the memory area pointed by the virtual address obtained with ioremap() is shifted by 1 Byte respect from what expected? And moreover, can I perform pointers arithmetic on the virtual address returned assuming it is contiguos like the physical ones?

Comment: What is the value of `MEMORY_ADDR`?

Comment: Problems I can see: (1) `res` is the virtual address to use, not `virt`. (2) The `ioremap_nocache` call is only mapping `BUF_SIZE*ELEM_SIZE` bytes, but the flags buffer immediately after that area hasn't been mapped. (3) You are not using the special functions intended for accessing ioremapped memory. (4) The `printk` format specifiers do not match the types of the arguments being printed (see [How to get printk format specifiers right](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html) but if you are using an older kernel, the details may differ).

Comment: Thanks for the reply: (1) I've corrected now and is no more crashing. (2) you right, the snippet of code I provided was a simplification of the real code (I removed access to structures containing info about size of such memory), I corrected the snippet accordingly (3) I've tryied using the readb() function and works fine (4) Thanks, I've corrected it. However, still a probelm remains: now I do not get any kernel panic accessing that memory, however the data which is read is shifted of 1 byte (see updated output)

Comment: where do I find the value of MEMORY_ADDR?

Answer (score 0):

The virtual address' returned by `ioremap` and `phys_to_virt` are not the same.

`ioremap`: creates a new mapping page table

`phys_to_virt`: substract a fixed offset from the address. Check MMU for phy_offset.

How to test?

```
void* addr1 = phys_to_virt(MEMORY_ADDR);
void* addr2 = ioremap_nocache(MEMORY_ADDR, BUF_SIZE*ELEM_SIZE);

printk(KERN_INFO "virt_addr1: %x\n", (unsigned int volatile *) addr1);
printk(KERN_INFO "virt_addr2: %x\n", (unsigned int volatile *) addr2);
```

You will see addr1 and addr2 are different. I think you dont need to use `phys_to_virt`.

Simply use:

```
void* virt_addr = ioremap_nocache(MEMORY_ADDR, BUF_SIZE*ELEM_SIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks @linkjumper, however the problem is that it seems that the phisical address associated to the virtual one returned by ioremap_nocache() is different from the one I gave it as input. I can notice it since the values that I read are different from the ones expected (such memory region has been initialized with known values) and by using virt_to_phys() I get a phisical address different from the one given as argument to ioremap. What's wrong?